# Integrating a custom 'change-list' page in a Django project

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a django project, and for one of the models in the project I've written my own 'change list' page: it contains a grid (I've used *jqgrid*) of all the objects of this model.

Now I want to integrate this page with all the existing pages that were generated using django admin pages system: I want my html page to contain the django's header, user authentication and so on.

So I added in the top of my html page:

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
```

That works just fine, the only problem is that the css files that are included in *base.html* are effecting the style of the grid as well, and it looks bad.

So how can I have this costume page integrated in my web project without having the django css files apply to it?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need those css, you can edit your `base.html`, adding a css block there, moving all css there, and redefining it empty on your custom page.

But I doubt it will solve your task, since other parts of page layout depends on those stylesheets, so you'll have to

- overwrite common css settings in a custom page specific css file
- rewrite original css to not affect your custom page elements